# Access Java project source folders from PDE Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

How can one access the *Source folders on build paths* as they can be seen in the *Java Build Path* settings page dynamically from within a PDE plug-in? I have access to a `IJavaProject` instance from which I can also access the `IProject` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://samindaw.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/list-java-source-folders-in-an-eclipse-project-in-the-workspace/) could be the solution you are looking for.